# Undo preventDefault on checkbox in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the user tries to check an unchecked checkbox (I do nothing if it's already checked), I prevent the checkbox from getting checked and validate it with an AJAX call. But I can't figure out how to "check" it again. I tried to use `$(this).trigger('click');` but it doesn't work.

I also tried moving `preventDefault` to the `fail` condition. But that made the call not work, ever. I guess because the AJAX call changes the scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
        if( $(this).prop('checked') &&  $(this).val()=='on' )
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var pivot_attendee_program = name.split(/\]\[|\[|\]/);
            var data = {
                        'pivot' : pivot_attendee_program[0],
                        'attendee_id' : pivot_attendee_program[1],
                        'program_id' : pivot_attendee_program[2]
                       };

            //console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '{{ route('ageCheck') }}',
                data: data,
                success: function(result){

console.log('success');
                    if(result == 'pass'){
                        console.log('pass');
                        $(this).trigger('click');
                    }
                    else{ //result == 'fail'

                        console.log('fail');

                    }


                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                }

            });

                    //validate Age
                    //ajax  check age of attendee against program                       
                    //ajax  check age of attendee against program_seg

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Explain this a little better. If the checkbos ***is*** checked you prevent the default behaviour and it's now unchecked, and then you like to check it again ?

Comment: `$(this).prop("checked", true)`

Comment: @Barmar - that's close, `this` isn't the element in the ajax success handler, otherwise I think that's the answer, but not sure ?

Comment: To get `this` into the AJAX success handler, use `context: this` in the `$.ajax` options.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614055/passing-post-variables-through-ajax/21614153#21614153

Comment: You can't call `preventDefault` in a callback function, since they're executed asynchronously. The default action will already have taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `context:` option to pass `this` through to the success function, then set the `checked` property of the box:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '{{ route('ageCheck') }}',
            data: data,
            context: this,
            success: function(result){
                console.log('success');
                if(result == 'pass'){
                    console.log('pass');
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                }
                else{ //result == 'fail'

                    console.log('fail');
                }
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });
```